# VIM: how to add search/replace command to vimrc and map to a shortcut

Tags: search, dictionary, replace, vim

I have two search/replace commands that I find myself running in vim fairly often to clean up html code so I can copy/paste it online.  The commands are:

```
:%s!<!\&lt;!g
:%s!>!\&gt;!g
```

I wanted a way I could map both of these commands to be run together ... I did some searching for how to use the `:map` commands in vimrc, however, I can't see how to combine the two lines into a single command that is run with a single keystroke (or a single sequence of strokes).

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put the commands on a single line separated with a bar.

```
:%s!<!\&lt;!g|%s!>!\&gt;!g
```

But you'll have to escape it in the `map` command

```
:map <F3> :%s!<!\&lt;!g\|:%s!>!\&gt;!g<CR>
```

Comment: This is almost right. In Vim, the second command won't be executed if the first command errors (which will happen if the first command finds no match). To suppress this behavior, add an `e` flag as follows: `:map <F3> :%s!<!\&lt;!ge\|:%s!>!\&gt;!ge<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

```
:TOhtml
```

will create a new buffer containing your previous buffer HTML-ized, including entity escaping (and syntax highlighting, if you had that enabled).  See [`:h TOhtml`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:TOhtml) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this search/replace pattern to HTML encode entities, you might want to check out the [unimpaired plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590). Amongst other things, this provides shortcuts for [encoding and decoding](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/014d55966e6f4971bb983e0b8e4f6b7edd708c91/doc/unimpaired.txt#L57) XML, URL and C strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
:map <F3> :%s!<!\&lt;!<cr>:%s!>!\&gt;!<cr>
```

of course  can be replaced with whatever key you wish

Comment: This didn't work if I had a couple in a row ... for example: `>>>` it would only replace the first one and then move on to the next line.

Comment: That's only because the 'g' modifier is missing.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm just too used to have `set gdefault` in my .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it, but can you not put them on the same line separated by `"<CR>"`?