# How to convert/paste a hex string as a list of bytes in vim?

Tags: c++, vim, arrays

Let's say we have a quite long hex string of the form:

```
112233..ddeeff
```

I'd like to use this string to initialize a container i.e. std::vector in C++.
Is there a way in vim to paste this as a list of bytes of the following form:

```
0x11, 0x22, 0x33 ... 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff
```

or alternatively paste the string in its original hex-string-form and then quickly transform it into the desired byte list form using visual selection and some shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a macro to transform the string and then associate it with a key. The following code transforms the word where the cursor is on into the desired byte list by pressing F2.

```
function! TransformHex2byte()
    " Get hex string, transform it, and delete the trailing ', '
    let l:new_word = substitute( substitute( expand("<cword>") , '\x\x', "0x&, " , 'g') , ', $', '', '' )

    " Change the old string with the new one.
    exec "normal ciw" . new_word . "\<Esc>"
endfunction

noremap <F2> :call TransformHex2byte()<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Use](https://xkcd.com/208/) regular expressions:

```
:s/\(\x\x\)/0x\1, /g
```

In VIM, `\x` matches a hex digit. `\(` and `\)` denote a subpattern which we reference using `\1` in the substitution. Add a *g*rain of `g` to make it apply to the whole line.

Comment: Yes regexp are a way. Since I happen to need that command quite often I was hoping to get around the necessity to type the regex every time. Do you know a way to bind that regex to a shortcut so that it pastes the "clipboard"-registers content applying the regex to it?

Comment: @norritt see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326159/1248008 I don’t know enough vim to know how to link that to pasting.